# Store the dependencies specified in pom.xml in the output zip file

Tags: maven

`Here i create a maven project and their no lib folder i specify all the required jars in the POM.XML i would to get all my jars from POM.XML file for that i give the plugins maven-assembly-plugin,maven-compiler-plugin,maven-dependency-plugin.`

`I create the assembly.XML file and run the process but the jars is not installed in the zip file.`
Here is my assembly.XML file

`can please help to me.`

Comment: Can you show the assembly.xml and your pom file?

Comment: Please, attach your `pom.xml`, `assembly.xml` and reformat your question to not use `\`` for everything.